# Running exe with parameters using batch

Tags: batch-file

How can I pass parameters into batch file running exe? I have program which requires 2 parameters, and I want to run it 5 five times using bat file with defined parameters. Something like that:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO start "path" program.exe -20 -15
```

where 20 and 15 are parameters. It doesn't recognize 20 and 15, so how can I define it?

Comment: does `program.exe -20 -15` work from command promt?

Comment: Unfortunately not. So there is a problem. I have c++ program where user needs to insert two numbers. I thought it will work this way

Answer (score 3):

If your `program.exe` accepts command line parameters, use `program.exe 20 15` to send parameters `20` and `15`, or `program.exe -20 -15` to send parameters `-20` and `-15`.

If the `"path"` represents *partial or full path* to `program.exe`:

```
 start "" "path\program.exe" 20 15
```

If the `"path"` should represent *working directory* for `program.exe`:

```
 start "" /D "path" program.exe 20 15
```

Read [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) docs for further modifications via facultative `[options]` in the following syntax pattern:

```
 START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

Answer (score 3):

according to your comment, you don't use parameters, but program input. That's a completely other story. Try:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (echo 20 & echo 15)|program.exe
```